# Get matched values between two dataframes using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes with multiple columns.

I would like to compare df1['id'] and df2['id'] and return a new df with The column["correct_id"] that have the match value. example:

**df1:**

```
     id      Name
0   123      Paul
1  c345      Jean
2     0    Alicia
3   345  Jennifer
```

**df2**

```
    id      Name
0  123      Paul
1  980      Jean
2    0    Alicia
3  945  Jennifer
```

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd 

df1=pd.DataFrame({'id':['123','c345','0','345'],
    'Name':['Paul','Jean','Alicia','Jennifer'],
})
print(df1)

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'id':[123,980,0,945],
    'Name':['Paul','Jean','Alicia','Jennifer'],})

print(df2)

df1['id'] = pd.to_numeric(df1['id'], errors='coerce')
df1["correct_id"] = (df1["id"].isin(df2["id"]) * df1["id"]).replace(0, "N/A")
print(df1)
```

I got **as an output:**

```
     id      Name correct_id
0  123.0      Paul      123.0
1    NaN      Jean        NaN
2    0.0    Alicia        N/A
3  345.0  Jennifer        N/A
```

**Expected Output:**

```
      id      Name correct_id
0    123      Paul        123
1    c345      Jean       N/A
2    0      Alicia        0
3   345  Jennifer        N/A
```

How can i fix this please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this:

```py
new_df = df1.copy()

new_df.loc[:, "correct_id"] = df1.loc[
    df1["id"].astype(str).isin(df2["id"].astype(str).values), "id"
]
new_df.fillna("N/A", inplace=True)

print(new_df)
# Outputs
     id      Name correct_id
0   123      Paul        123
1  c345      Jean        N/A
2     0    Alicia          0
3   345  Jennifer        N/A
```